# when pass string to bash script with pytest result is cutting

Tags: python, bash, pytest

Have a python script (excess cut out)

```
def run_shell_test(script, *args):

    out = check_output([script] + list(args), universal_newlines=True)
    return out.split("\n")[0]

def test_log_2():
    message = "This is a test message"
    now = datetime.now()

    result = run_shell_test('./tests/test_log.sh', f"{message}")
    assert result == f"[{now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}] {message}"
```

there is a bash script that does a simple thing

```
print_log() {
  log_date=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
  echo "[$log_date] $1"
}
```

When i run pytest, it doesn't show what i expected:

```
[2022-12-13 11:56] This
```

What i expect:

```
[2022-12-13 11:56] This is a test message
```

When i run command bash script via bash, everything ok.

```
print_log "This is a test message"
[2022-12-13 08:31] "This is a test message"
```

looks like python "eats" my quotes.

Comment: have you tried placing quotes for your param like so: `result = run_shell_test('./tests/test_log.sh', f"\"{message}\"")`?

Comment: @sudden_appearance
I just tried it, it didn't help

Comment: Is the missing "`is a test message`" appearing somewhere else in the output of pytest? When you check this, please redirect the output to a file and inspect the file with an editor, not on a terminal, so that we can rule out problems with potential carriage returns (`\r`).

Comment: @sudden_appearance OP is not using `shell=True`, so there should be no quotes in there, except if `test_log.sh` itself expects them to be there. But then OP had to include them in their bash command too, e.g. `./tests/test_log.sh '"This is a test message"'` (note the outer `'`).

Comment: looks like python "eats" my quotes.
when i run bash without a quotes `print_log This is a test message` it gave me the same result like python `[2022-12-13 08:37] This`

Comment: @Socowi
`Is the missing "is a test message" appearing somewhere else in the output of pytest?`
no, i didnt find it.
If you mean redirect bash script to file and check it, im done it, everything ok :(

Comment: Thanks all for your help, it was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This my bad...
i solve it with this, adding $@, instead previous version @1

```
print_log() {
  log_date=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
  echo "[$log_date] $@"
}
```

Comment: The function `print_log` should work with `$1` too. The actual error has to be somewhere else in your script file `test_log.sh`. I assume you call the function as `print_log $1` where the unquoted `$1` causes word splitting. Run your script through https://shellcheck.net/ to find errors like these.